# VBS to combine Excel columns

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for VBS that can automatically combine all columns to single one, table to column...appreciate for your support.

ROW1| A   D   G
ROW2| B   E   H
ROW3| C   F   I

Expected result:

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I

Comment: Include what you have tried already. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
Option Explicit
'Var's Used
Dim oXLApp, oSheet, sXlFile, sWorkSheet, iStartRow, iEndRow
Dim iStartColumn, iEndColumn, iRowIndex, iColIndex, sValue

'Set file path and name to excel file that contains the data
sXlFile = "E:\Sample.xls"
sWorkSheet = "Sheet1"

'Set the start & end rows and columns
iStartRow = 1
iEndRow = 3
iStartColumn = 1
iEndColumn = 3

'Create the excel object
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Make it visible
oXLApp.Visible = True

'Open the workbook
oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(sXlFile)

'Create the worksheet object
Set oSheet = oXLApp.Sheets(sWorkSheet)

'Row loop
For iRowIndex = iStartRow To iEndRow
  'Column loop
  For iColIndex = iStartColumn To iEndColumn
    'Get the Value of the cell
    sValue = oSheet.Cells(iRowIndex,iColIndex).Value
    'So something with the value
    WScript.Echo sValue
  Next
Next

'Distroy the sheet object
Set oSheet = Nothing

'Close the workbook
oXLApp.Workbooks.Close

'Exit Excel
oXLApp.Quit

'Distroy the XLApp object
Set oXLApp = Nothing
```